# ipad add tableview (only a part) to viewcontroller with storyboard

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

So I'm trying to add a UITableView on the lower half of my ipad app which will be used to display a search result. This is how I did it.

1. I added a UIView
2. I added a UItableView onto the UIView
3. I then dragged the UITableView to the ViewController so it can connect to it for delegate and datasource.

This is what it currently looks like:

(It's at that middle top row)

[image]

So I added the following onto the viewcontroller class to generate the data

```
# pragma mark TableView properties

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 2;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SearchResultCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"test";
}
```

The debugger would go through all these but would get stuck after the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method:

[image]

It would just go through that and would not end until I stop the whole debugging. Not really sure what's going on.

Thoughts? Maybe you guys can point me to the right direction as to how I should generate my search results.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I usually find it much more faster and easier to use the free Sensible TableView framework to do automatic table view searches, instead of using the regular datasource/delegate system which I could never get right.